# How to work with nested array in .ts file

Tags: arrays, angular

I have the below json array which my service.ts get request returned. I will like to know how I can grab the value of "university" and "course" from all the objects and store it in a new array.

**content of staff array**

```
[
  {"id": 11, "name": "Anna", "education": [
       {"university": "oxford", "course": "administration", "year": "2013"},
       {"university": "lincon", "course": "receptionist", "year": "2010"}
     ]
  },
  {"id": 47, "name": "John", "education": [
       {"university": "toronto", "course": "electrical", "year": "1997"},
       {"university": "ambro", "course": "industrail", "year": "1990"}
     ]
  },
  {"id": 85, "name": "William", "education": [
       {"university": "ambro", "course": "zoology", "year": "2010"},
       {"university": "ambro", "course": "biology", "year": "2001"}
     ]
  }
]
```

**comp.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getstaff()
      .subscribe((res) => {
          this.staff = res;
          this.staffDetail = // I want to store education details here
       });
 }
```

How do I apply "find" or "filter" on **staff** array to get value of "university" and "course". How to I code the .ts file. I want the content of **staffDetail** to look like below.

**content of staffDetail array**

```
[
{"education": [
     {"university": "oxford", "course": "administration"},
     {"university": "lincon", "course": "receptionist"}
  ]
},
{"education": [
     {"university": "toronto", "course": "electrical"},
     {"university": "ambro", "course": "industrail"}
  ]
},
{"education": [
     {"university": "ambro", "course": "zoology"},
     {"university": "ambro", "course": "biology"}
  ]
}
]
```

Do let me know if I need to explain further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to do that.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getstaff().subscribe((res) => {
     this.staff = res;
     this.staffDetails = this.staff.map(item => ({
       "education": item.education.map(obj => ({
         "university": obj.university,
         "course": obj.course
        }))
     }));
   });
 }
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var staff = [ {"id": 11, "name": "Anna", "education": [ {"university": "oxford", "course": "administration", "year": "2013"}, {"university": "lincon", "course": "receptionist", "year": "2010"} ] }, {"id": 47, "name": "John", "education": [ {"university": "toronto", "course": "electrical", "year": "1997"}, {"university": "ambro", "course": "industrail", "year": "1990"} ] }, {"id": 85, "name": "William", "education": [ {"university": "ambro", "course": "zoology", "year": "2010"}, {"university": "ambro", "course": "biology", "year": "2001"} ] } ];

var staffDetails = staff.map(item => ({
  "education": item.education.map(obj => ({
    "university": obj.university,
    "course": obj.course
  }))
}));

console.log(staffDetails);
```